# would torify use the same circuit as tbb when both are in operation?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, circuit, guard-node, torify

Let's say I'm using both tbb and torify at the same time. For e.g. I'm using tor to browser/look at tor.stackexchange.com. At the same time I am running torify on a different url say https://aaa.bbb.ccc (just a hypothetical url at moment, although it probably might be registered by a domain hoarder but that's a different topic) . Now in such a scenario would both be using the same cricuit, nodes, path etc. or would both use different circuits 
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Tor Browser isolates it's circuits by the first party domain.

e.g. *foo.com*, *bar.foo.com* and *qux.bar.foo.com* will all be isolated on their own circuit for *foo.com*. While *example.com*, *bar.example.com* and *qux.bar.example.com* will all use their own isolated circuit for *example.com*.

Anything under `torify` won't use the same SOCKS5 credentials and so won't use the same circuit. However, multiple applications under `torify` will share the same circuit since it doesn't perform any kind of isolation by default. Advanced configuration of `torify` (or `torsocks`) will allow for isolation, if required.